# How to See Write Growth on MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql

Yesterday, I noticed that one specific table started getting a lot of inserts. And I would like to proactively know about "write" growth on any tables. I am on MySQL 8.0.28.

So, I thought of running a query like this and then saving the output in sqlite3.

```
 SELECT current_date(), object_type, object_schema, object_name
     , count_star, count_read, count_write, count_fetch
     , count_insert, count_update, count_delete
  FROM performance_schema.table_io_waits_summary_by_table
 WHERE count_star > 0
 ORDER BY count_star DESC
```

Then, later on, I have to write an SQL to see which table has grown over a couple of months.

1. Does MySQL have some built-in functions to get this information?
2. Is there a better/simpler way to do this to get the "write" growth of any table?
3. Are there tools out there that can give me this information? I checked PMM (Percona Monitoring Tool) but I don't see the same information. It shows the largest table but what I am after is the rate of writes of a table.

Comment: Percona Server has `information_schema.table_stats` (https://docs.percona.com/percona-server/8.0/user-stats.html), but I don't think anything like that is implemented in MySQL.

Comment: "Write growth" implies (to me) "table size", but "rate of writes" implies (to me) "inserts per second" or maybe "inserts/updates per second".  Please clarify the goal.  If it is "table size", then do you want "MB" or "row count"?  Can there be `DELETEs`?